# Angular animate view transitions depending on origin and destination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate, ngroute

I'm new to Angular animations and I'm having problems with transitioning route views with animations.

I'm using ng-route and ng-animate.

Lets say that I have three views: page1.html, page2.html and page3.html which are shown in my index file with ng-view depending on the url (/page1, /page2 and /page3).

Now if the current url is /page1 (and the page1.html is shown), I know how to add CSS classes using ng-enter and ng-leave to make the transitions between the pages to animate nicely. What I'm having trouble with is how to handle different animations in different states.

For example, if I add all the CSS rules to make page1 slide out to the left when leaving url /page1 and page2 to slide in from the right when entering url /page2, everything is nice. But what if I want the transition between page1 -> page3 to be sliding page1 out down and page3 sliding down from the top?

This is what I want to have:

- page1 -> page2 (slide left effect)
- page2 -> page1 (slide right effect)
- page1 -> page3 (slide down effect)
- page3 -> page1 (slide up effect)
- page2 -> page3 (fade in effect)
- page3 -> page2 (fade in effect)

As you can see, my animations depend on the origin and destination url/page, not simply if the page is entering or leaving. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: check this plunkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/sIWfBnHww9EVi9TuphTv

## Using ngRoute theory...

The way I do this, is by adding a state attribute to the body tag. For this, you need to make $route available on

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
.run(function($rootScope, $location){
  $rootScope.$route = $location;
})

.controller('MyCtrl', function($rootScope, $location){
   $rootScope.previousLocation;
   $rootScope.newLocation;
   $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
     $rootScope.previousLocation = $location.path();
   })
   $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){
     $rootScope.newLocation = $location.path();
   })
})
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl" new-location="{{ newLocation }}">
```

This, however, sucks b*lls as your CSS selectors for animations would be something like `[new-location*="Books/view"] .ng-enter-active{}`.

## Using far superior ui.router

I would recommend using `ui-router` to manage your **states** to make this a little easier. Since all states are named, you can attach the current state:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
.run(function($rootScope, $state){
   $rootScope.$state = $state;
})

<body state="{{ $state.current.name }}">
```

In which case your CSS selectors to animate would be something like this:

```
body[state="books.view"] [ui-view].ng-enter{}
```

Sorry... that's all a bit jibberish. See the plunkr for working example.

... SEE THIS PLUNKR http://plnkr.co/edit/sIWfBnHww9EVi9TuphTv

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. I too were able to know which state my app is in at a moment, by a similar method provided by you with the ngRoute example. However, I feel that your answer is lacking one thing: Being able to have different ng-enter's of for example "books.view" depending on which state it transits from. TLDR: I need to make CSS animations based on previous state and new state, not only current state. I updated your plunkr a bit to show what I want: http://plnkr.co/edit/y6qL5tGyM4lh0PfR1fAc
I hope you understand what I want :)